# Check variables in Javascript fails

Tags: javascript

I've made a card drawing programm to draw three cards.
Now I like to avoid that one card is added multiple times.
So, I made a little function to check:

```
 function check()
    {
    if (card2 == card1 || card3 == card2 || card3 == card1 )
        {
        alert("double card")

        }
     };
```

When I check the variables with console.log they all different.
But the alert is always popping up.
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: And what are the values of variables when alert fires?

Comment: Cardx is the name of a variabel f.i. card50.jpg

Comment: After the function no semikolon!

Comment: the semikolon makes no difference.

Comment: How you pass cards variables. Are they globals? If not you should pass them by function arguments: function check(card1, card2, card3) {...}

Comment: before the if statement, add `console.log(card1, card2, card3)` and post the results.

Comment: Actually I don't know. I generate my variables by:    for (var i = 1; i < 78; i++) {
            document.write("<div id=" + ("kaart" + i) + ">" + "<img src='" + ("images/kaart" + kaart[i] + ".jpg") + "' width='110' height='180' onclick='showDiv(event)'/></div>");
        };

Comment: @itdoesntwork: the result of another console.log is: card20.jpg, but the console.log in the js file generates: 0 0 0 !

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK with this piece of code. Simple check:

```
var card1 = 'one',
    card2 = 'two',
    card3 = 'three';

function check()
{
    if (card2 == card1 || card3 == card2 || card3 == card1 )
    {
        alert("double card")
    }
    else {
        alert("they are different");
    }
}

check();
```

Leve demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/sy4tetwn/

The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have a function called showDiv, consisting of a switch. In the second and third case, the function is called (which is in a seperate (linked) js-file. So the console.log in the html file is giving the right result and the console.log in the js-file is returning zero's.

Comment: @user3107597 Did you include js-file before you run function `check()` ?

Comment: Yes, I included the js-file in the head section. But even when I include the function in the same file, the results of the console.logs as described above are the same.

Comment: so, it is not possible to find the solution without fulltext example.

Comment: It's a long story. Can I send it to your email adress?

Comment: The code is too big to paste here and I am not authorised to chat. Jsfiddle I have to explore (tomorrow).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your contribution. I finally found a solution. I was triggered by the remark of  itdoesntwork to state the results of the console.log IN the function.

```
function check()
    {
        var result1=" "
        var result2=" "
        var result3=" "
        result1= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.positie1)
        result2= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.positie2)
        if (ak == 3) {
        result3= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.positie3)
        }
        //console.log(result1, result2, result3);
        if (result2 == result1 || result3 == result2 || result3 == result1 )
        {
        alert("double card")
        ak=ak-1;
        }
     }
```