# php syntax in if-then-else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a card program which selects cards from number 1 to 78. In the end I like to store the results in a database which requires a number; 7 characters long where the last 2 numbers are reserved for the cardnumber. So, with card 1-9 I add 6 numbers and otherwise I add 5 numbers to complete the range.

The echo f.i. gives the number 21. Still I get a cardnumber with a length of 8 characters instead of 7.

```
echo $krtnum2;
if ($krtnum2 < 10) {
      echo $krtnum2;
      $kaart2 = 102020 . $krtnum2;
      echo "length is 1 digit, cardnumber is: ";
      echo $kaart2;
} else {
      echo $krtnum2;
      $kaart2 = 10202 . $krtnum2;
      echo "length is 2 digits, cardnumber is: ";
      echo $kaart2;
}
```

What is wrong about this code?

Comment: you are missing a closing curly brace at the end.

Comment: What about the closing bracket from the else block?

Comment: That's a copy-paste fault. In my code it is present.

Comment: what is it printing out?

Comment: The print is: 2121length is 1 digit, cardnumber is: 10202021

Comment: Are you sure there is a problem? http://codepad.viper-7.com/RBaNf2

Comment: Yes, 21 is not less than 10, so it should go to the 'else' loop.

Comment: yea, but I just tried exactly the code you posted, as you can see in the link I posted and it worked perfectly fine. I did nothing but set `$krtnum2` to 9 and then 21. both come out fine. Try doing a `var_dump($krtnum2);` before the if statement.

Comment: Then the output is: 21string(40) "21" 21length is 1 digit, cardnumber is: 10202021

Comment: ok, and now try to view source on the page and see what it shows. That var dump says the variable has a data type of "string" (not int) and is 40 characters long. I'm assuming you have some html that is in there also and is not visible. viewing the source of the page will show the html. So the actual value in your variable is something like `<div id="someid" class="some class es">21</div>`. You won't see the div from simply echo'ing it out.

Comment: In the console (chrome) I only see:  krtnum2 :21. But you are right another part of the code is in html. So, do I need to use another type of variable?

Comment: The source is: <script>document.write(krtnum2)</script>string(40) "<script>document.write(krtnum2)</script>"
<script>document.write(krtnum2)</script>length is 1 digit, cardnumber is: 102020<script>document.write(krtnum2)</script>

Comment: if it has anything to do with your other question the answer you posted yourself http://stackoverflow.com/a/26212165/ then `var result1=" "` could have a bearing on this, where it seems like you're adding a space and maybe doing `var result1=""` etc.. I'm not 100% sure about this though, however you may want to `trim()` and make sure it's an integer by using `(int)`.

Comment: Ok, it's clear in which area I have to find a solution. Thanks for all of your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the most appropriate way to achieve your goal to use `str_pad` [function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php) like this:
`$kaart2 = 10202 . str_pad($krtnum2, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`